# How to match a link to a menu item

Tags: jquery

I have the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/0p4s3uwf/7/

There is a additional link in the page item2, so without clicking on the menu, i want to click on the addtional item2 link so that the menu gets highlighted.

```
$('#sb-navigation li').click(function() {
    $('#sb-navigation li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: `$('#sb-navigation li a.item2').parent().addClass('selected');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to highlight the `item2` menu items when the user clicks on the item2 link.

Add the event handler like this:

```
$('.item2').click(function() {
    $('#sb-navigation li').removeClass('selected'); //remove the selection from the other lis
    $('#sb-navigation li a.item2').parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kmoe/h72t8ea7/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `trigger('click')`

```
<a class="tabtarget" data-target="item2" href="#">item2</a>

<script>
$(".tabtarget").click(function(){
    $("#sb-navigation li a."+$(this).data("target")).trigger('click')
})
</script>
```

[Full Code](http://jsfiddle.net/0p4s3uwf/19/)